# what is the type of a here

Tags: types, coq

I found this code

```
Lemma foldlP T S f (s : seq T) x0 (I : nat -> S -> Prop) : 
I 0%N x0 -> 
(forall i x a, (i < size s)%N -> I i x -> I i.+1 (f x (nth a s i))) -> 
I (size s) (foldl f x0 s).
```

[here](http://poleiro.info/posts/2019-12-24-a-verification-challenge.html) and am trying to understand how it works. I think I get the general idea, but I can't figure out what type the variable a is, or, indeed, what purpose it is serving as an argument to nth. I can't run the code on my own IDE as I have looked around for a Seq library in coq and have not found one. Based on my general understanding of sequences alone, I have no clue what information the a is carrying.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `a` is of type `T`.  Its purpose is to provide a default element to the `nth` function when it is applied to an empty sequence `s`.

To run this code (which is available on [GitHub](https://github.com/arthuraa/poleiro/blob/master/theories/Fulcrum.v)), you need to install some of the Mathematical Components libraries. I believe that you just need the following:

```
opam install coq-mathcomp-ssreflect
opam install coq-mathcomp-algebra
```